# How to make ping more persistent with unresolved hostnames

Tags: unix, ping, hostname, persistent

When I try to ping a hostname of a computer that is down, I get en error that it cannot resolve the hostname.

```
$ alice:~ me$ ping bob
ping: cannot resolve bob: Unknown host
```

Is there a way I can make ping more persistent? I want it to keep trying so I can see when `bob` comes back online.

Comment: Do you expect the name to resolve when the host comes up?

Comment: @Ignacio: Yes, that's what I expect. And it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a)

```
while true; do
    ping bob || sleep 1
done
```

or

```
until ping bob; do
    sleep 1
done
```

or b) Configure a name resolution method that doesn't rely on the target host being up. `/etc/hosts` for the lazy.

Comment: Nice and simple, I like it.

Comment: redirect stderr to /dev/null if you don't want unknown host spam